# Why Google API for QR code is not working now?

Tags: google-api, qr-code

I am using the this API since 1 year but now I don't know why it stops working. Image of QR code creates but its not readable by browser. I sharing the test URL of the API
https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=World&choe=UTF-8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google turned it off:

https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/making_charts

I've same problem

Comment: This one could be an alternative option with same parameters as Google:

https://image-charts.com/chart?chs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=Hello%20world&choe=UTF-8